# Please add [websockets] as a synonym of [websocket]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

I noticed that there are [websocket](/questions/tagged/websocket) and [websockets](/questions/tagged/websockets) tags. They have 170 questions and 16 questions, respectively. It would make sense to **make [websockets](/questions/tagged/websockets) a synonym of [websocket](/questions/tagged/websocket)**.

The top scores page shows that "*all time top user*" has a score of 27 - quite far off from the required 2500. So, could the diamond mod apply this change, as there is nobody else with permissions to do it?

Comment: Usually we prefer to make the plural tag the master tag, but that requires a mod to set it up. +1 for finding this, though.

Comment: I just assumed that the one with more questions seems more natural to people, thus, the one with less questions should be the synonym. But I guess you know better, what the best practice is. :-)